# Broken Earth Trilogy: Steel's motivations/reasoning

Tags: broken-earth

I just finished the Broken Earth trilogy and am left wondering what exactly Steel's motivations/reasoning for his actions were.

Steel, aka Gray Man, aka Nassun’s stone eater aka Remwha at various occasions opposes or even fights Hoa and Essun.

> Steel instigates the attack on Castrima-under and almost successfully manipulates (if that's the right word) Nassun into smashing the Moon into Earth.

In Hoa's telling at the end of the book:

> [Steel] says: “I only wanted it to end.”
>  
>  Gaewha – Antimony, whatever – says, “That isn’t what we were made for.”
>  
>  He turns his head, slowly, to look at her. It is tiring just to watch him do this. Stubborn fool. There is the despair of ages on his face, all because he refuses to admit that there’s more than one way to be human.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Steel wanted to die.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhoWantsToLiveForever)**

> Being a stone eater means Steel's life force is tied to that of Father Earth's.  Hoa even mentions that the other stone eaters he has to tear apart to protect Essun will reform over time.  The only way he can see to end his own life is to end Earth's.  Using the wayward Moon to smash the Earth is the only way he can see to do that.

One of Steel's last conversations with Nassun has perhaps the strongest burst of emotions we ever see from any stone eater.  Nassun is desperate to save Schaffa's life, and Steel berates her about selfishly clinging to Schaffa.

> "I am forty thousand years old," Steel says. "Give or take a few millennia."
>
> ...
>
> "You're going to die when you open the Gate," Steel says, after giving Nassun a moment to absorb what he's said. "Or if not then, sometime after. A few decades, a few minutes, it's all the same.  And whatever you do, Schaffa will lose you.  He'll lose the one thing that has kept him human throughout the Earth's efforts to devour his will.  He'll find no one new to love, either - not here. And he won't be able to return to the Stillness unless he's willing to risk the Deep Earth route again.  So whether he heals somehow, or you change him into one of my kind, he will have no choice but to go on, alone, endlessly yearning for what he will never again have."  Slowly, Steel's arms lower to his sides. "You have no idea what that's like."
>
> And then, suddenly, shockingly, he is right in front of Nassun.  No blurring, no warning, just flick and he is *there*, bent at the waist to put his face right in front of hers, so close that she feels the wind of the air he's displaced and smells the whiff of loam and she can even see that the irises of his eyes are striated in layers of gray.
>
> "**BUT I DO**," he shouts.
>
> *The Stone Sky*, chapter 14, Nassun, not alone

His attack on Castrima-under was an attempt to put Essun in the same mental space Nassun arrived at naturally - mainly, his, tired of suffering and wanting to end it all.

This is in direct contrast to Hoa's approach...

> ...of doing his damnedest to preserve Essun, to the point of telling her entire life story to the new stone eater created from her remains.  Not only Hoa, but Schaffa himself, and many other characters, find someone else to share their lives with, or to keep themselves anchored with.  Hoa is simply finding his own way to be human, immortality and transmutations aside, which is why he despairs of Steel's unwillingness to change in the lines you quote.

Comment: Wouldn't have gotten what he wanted anyway, with Earth's last play and Nassun's change of plans, but that's about the sum of it.

Comment: Thanks, sounds plausible! Although I have to admit that it's been a while since I read the books...

Comment: @mb21 - yeah, I just finished them recently, pity you had to wait that long for an answer.  It was a great series, but definitely a grim read in many parts, probably why it's not more widely read.